# How to change profile picture in User Accounts

Tags: user-profile

I can't somehow not change the profile picture in User Accounts. After I browse for a photo and select one, nothing happens! Rebooting doesn't fix the problem. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. How can I fix this problem and change my picture?

**for the close voters: re-read, this is a perfect and valid question**

Comment: What Ubuntu version and desktop environment are you using?

Comment: 16.04 LTS..and I don't know which desktop! The default one I guess

Comment: Confirming this problem, it seems to be a bug. However, it worked at least once for me, because two weeks ago I changed the icon to a custom JPG without any issues, therefore I think the error has to be in one of the updates that 16.04 received. .

Comment: Reported this as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1582876

Comment: Just found out that my bug report is a duplicate of this one here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/1581567

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. Recent upgrade from 15.10. In 15.10, it worked just fine within the account. In 16.04, I had to change the profile picture from a dummy account.

Comment: That worked for me. But the next question is *why* on earth they would do this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot change the image of the user that is currently logged in. for the other accounts, you can change the image, but you must first click the Unlock button at the right top.

Comment: I tried that, i clicked the unlock button. and then selected the profile picture, still no luck

Comment: i'm using the gnome version, Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug as you can see in both bug reports here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1582876
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/1581567

It has been fixed at 18.05.2016 10:53 GMT +1. The `accountservice` and the `control-center` should behave normaly now again.